# Open Save Cancel dialogue not coming for IE10 for HTML file

Tags: html, servlets, internet-explorer-10, attachment

Upto IE 8, if we try to open an attached HTML file, we can see Open-Save-Cancel dialogue. However in IE-10, Open option is not coming. Only Save-Cancel is coming. Is it removed due to some kind of security issue? If yes, is there any workaround to fix this?

We are using below code to open HTML file - (this might be irrelevent as the same code is working fine till IE-8. It's just for reference)

```
InputStream in = fileToBeDisplayed.getBinaryStream();
OutputStream fr = response.getOutputStream();   
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename="abc.html");
response.setContentType("text/html");
int b;
while ((b = in.read()) != -1)
{
  fr.write(b);
}
in.close();                      
fr.flush();                     
fr.close();
```

For reference : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/3094ac49-8d49-4a60-a7cf-fb12c823e500/ie9-download-manager-will-not-display-open-option-only-save-and-cancel-is-displayed-for?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Comment: This shouldn't even compile because the quotes in the `response.setHeader(` line are not handled properly. Also try a space between the `;` and `filename`.

Comment: Also please specify whether you meant IE10 on RT or fullblown Windows 8.  Did you try it on both or just on RT?